# Angular performance jqLite vs VanilaJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

The other day I was reading a post in SitePoint and I found a JavaScript API used quickly measure performance ([`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)). I decided to do a quick test with Angular and I can't figure out why using `angular.element` is faster than using vanillaJS to, for example, remove a class in a given element.

Here is the code:

```
  var t0 = performance.now();
  document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].className = "";
  var t1 = performance.now();
  console.log(t1 - t0 + ' ms')

  var t2 = performance.now();
  angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('demo')).removeClass('demo');
  var t3 = performance.now();
  console.log(t3 - t2 + ' ms ')
```

Is this reliable?

Comment: Most likely if you switch the tests (ie. the angular test first), the performance will be different. You can't do benchmarks on single functions like that, first you'd need each test to run in a freshly opened browser independent of the other test and second, you should have lots of iterations.

Comment: How often have you tried? Have you tried to put angular first? ...

Comment: Because `getElementsByClassName` is not going to perform the same search on entire document the second time. The second time it will use previous results (sort of cached).